# conf.d not generated during installed

Tags: apache

i have tried to install httpd by compiling from source on CentOS7 and the conf.d directory is not generated

1) Downloaded Sources `httpd-2.4.38.tar.gz`
2) extracted it

```
   gzip -d httpd-2.4.38.tar.gz
   tar xvf 2.4.38.tar
```

2) Downloaded `apr-1.6.5.tar.gz,apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz`

3) extracted them

```
   gzip -d  apr-1.6.5.tar.gz apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
   tar xvf apr-1.6.5.tar apr-util-1.6.1.tar
```

4) copied to libsrc directory

5) installed pcre

6) configured

```
  ./configure --prefix=/home/raju/httpd --with-pcre=/path/to/pcre --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util
```

7) `make`

8)`make install`

Comment: Why do not install from repo?

Comment: for our production as per our org compliance we need to place in a different path than default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory in question is part of distribution package. If you insist to use it you can create it by hand. But what you can do also is to download the RPM source files, install them, edit SPECS files to reflect new installation position. Also here you can add in postinstall actions creation of directory `conf.d`. Build packages with `rpmbuild` command. Then you can install them